# usb disk affected by surprise removal

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I got a surprise removal of my USB drive. Now it is detected in device manager, but not showing neither in my computer nor in disk management.

Please help me.

Here are my USB details:

```
      ========================== Disk ============================
Disk Size         = not found
Disk Geometry     = 941 Cylinders, 255 Heads, 63 Sectors per Track, 512 Bytes per Sector
Disk Writable     = FILE_NOT_FOUND
Disk Attributes   = offline
PtMgr DiskId GUID = {d0ff2de1-5c5f-11e4-8288-b888e3b5b24a}
Volume Count      = 0
Bus Type          = USB
USB LocationIds   = PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1D00)#USBROOT(0)#USB(1)#USB(1), ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(EHC1)#ACPI(HUBN)#ACPI(PR01)#ACPI(PR11)
USB ContainerId   = {ba44519b-88ff-5bf5-9f7a-94e0f380636e}
Drive Type        = no root
Device Types      = Untested
DevID             = USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DT_101_G2&REV_1.00\000FEAFAAB63FD11F7F44FC1&0
USB   DevID       = USB\VID_0951&PID_1642\000FEAFAAB63FD11F7F44FC1
Host Ctrl DevID   = PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1E26&SUBSYS_06491025&REV_04\3&11583659&0&E8
Host Controller   = Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1E26
KernelNames       = \Device\Harddisk1\DR2, \Device\00000053
Win32 Device      = \\.\PhysicalDrive1
DevicePath        = \\?\USBSTOR#Disk&Ven_Kingston&Prod_DT_101_G2&Rev_1.00#000FEAFAAB63FD11F7F44FC1&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
Removal Policy    = surprise removal ('Optimize for quick removal')
Hotplug Device    = yes
Hotplug Media     = no
Removable Media   = yes
Command Queueing  = no
Friendly Name     = Kingston DT 101 G2 USB Device
Requested Power   = 100 mA (bus powered)
USB Version       = 2.0 (High-Speed)
USB Friendly Name = Kingston DT 101 G2
USB Serial        = 000FEAFAAB63FD11F7F44FC1
USB Port Name     = 2-1-1

          ---------------- USBDLM Criteria -------------------
DeviceID=USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DT_101_G2&REV_1.00\000FEAFAAB63FD11F7F44FC1&0
DeviceID=USB\VID_0951&PID_1642\000FEAFAAB63FD11F7F44FC1
DriveType=NO_ROOT
BusType=USB
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 8.1, hard disks, attached to SuperSpeed USB 3.0 ports, unexpectedly disappear from the system and File Explorer, formerly known as Windows Explorer (standing behind “This PC” – formerly “My Computer” icon on the desktop, if present) does not show them anymore even though nobody has physically disconnect them, or powered them off.

This is a very unpleasant, annoying, potentially harmful and sometimes even dangerous energy saving “wisdom”, implemented by Windows 8.1 designers. It can halt and corrupt data transfers, programmed backups, etc.

To prevent it from happening, you need to do two things, and their order is irrelevant. For instance, firstly, you open Power Options in Control Panel and choose hyperlink “Change plan settings” in the section “Preferred plans”. New window opens, allowing changes to be made to a power plan, and you choose (click) the hyperlink “Change advanced plan settings”. This opens, in addition to the previous window, entitled “Edit Plan Settings”, a smaller one, entitled “Power Options’. This one has only one tab, entitled “Advanced Settings”. In its window, scroll down to the section “USB settings” and expand it, e. g., by clicking it. Then expand its only subsection, entitled “USB selective suspend settings” and expand it the same way. Here you can, and should make a first step of disabling this devilish conjecture of Microsoft gurus.

Second, and the last one, is made in Device Manager. To open it, right-click the lower left corner of the Desktop and choose Device Manager. Somewhere close to or at the end of devices, shown by type, find “Universal Serial Bus controllers” and expand them. At the bottom of their list are one or two “USB Root Hub (xHCI)”. Open their Properties, e. g. by double-clicking them, and select the last (rightmost) tab “Power Management”. In it, uncheck the box “Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power”. Then press OK virtual button on the bottom of this “USB Root Hub (xHCI) Properties” window. That’s it. Close all these windows and enjoy a calm life!

Comment: Its still called Windows Explorer by the way.